# PHP, How can I insert my CSV file into my Database

Tags: php, mysql, csv, pdo

Hi I am trying to so that when I add a new csvfile to my folder it will be inserted into my database, but I have no idea how to do so.
Here an eksample of my csv file https://i.gyazo.com/5f97c964c12f9f38fe4f6fbc901158a8.png

I'll show my `DB.php` class first i will be using that to execute my data.

**I know that there are shown 2 tables in this code, that for testing that I get the correct data**

```
<?php

class DB extends \PDO
{
    /**
     * @var
     */
    private $host;
    /**
     * @var
     */
    private $user;
    /**
     * @var
     */
    private $pass;
    /**
     * @var PDO
     */
    private $conn;
    /**
     * @var
     */
    private $query;
    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    private $debug = false;


    /**
     * @param bool $bool
     */
    public function debug($bool = true)
    {
        $this->debug = $bool;
    }

    /**
     * @param $sql
     */
    private function setQuery($sql)
    {
        $this->query = $this->prepare($sql);
    }

    /**
     * DB constructor.
     * @param $dbhost
     * @param $dbuser
     * @param $dbpass
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function __construct($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $options = [])
    {
        try {
            $this->conn = parent::__construct($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $options);
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            print "Fejl!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
            die();
        }

    }


    /**
     * @param string $sql
     * @param bool $params
     * @param int|mixed|null $returnType
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function query($sql, $params = false, $returnType = \PDO::FETCH_OBJ)
    {
        $this->setQuery($sql);
        $this->execute($params);
        $this->count = $this->query->rowCount();

        return $this->query->fetchAll($returnType);
    }

    /**
     * @param $params
     */
    private function execute($params)
    {
        if($params){
            $this->query->execute($params);
        } else {
            $this->query->execute();
        }
        if($this->debug){
            echo '<pre id="debug_params">',$this->query->debugDumpParams(),'</pre>';
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $sql
     * @param bool $params
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function single($sql, $params = false){
        $data = $this->query($sql, $params);
        if(sizeof($data) === 1){
            return $data[0];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $sql
     * @param bool $params
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function first($sql, $params = false){
        return $this->query($sql, $params)[0];
    }

    /**
     * @param $sql
     * @param bool $params
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function last($sql, $params = false){
        return $this->query($sql, $params)[$this->count - 1];
    }

    /**
     * @param $sql
     * @param bool $params
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function toList($sql, $params = false){
        return $this->query($sql, $params);
    }

    /**
     * @param $sql
     * @param bool $params
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function lastId($sql, $params = false){
        $this->query($sql, $params);
        return $this->lastInsertId();
    }
}
```

And this is my `csvtable.php` my index file, this is what the user will see.

```
<?php
if ($user->is_loggedin() == true) {

// File selector
    $path = "./assets/csv"; 

    $latest_ctime = 0;
    $latest_filename = '';    

    $d = dir($path);
    while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
    $filepath = "{$path}/{$entry}";
    // could do also other checks than just checking whether the entry is a file
        if (is_file($filepath) && filectime($filepath) > $latest_ctime){
            $latest_ctime = filectime($filepath);
            $latest_filename = $entry;
        }
    }

// File selector end

    echo'<h1 class="text-center">CSV Table</h1>';
    echo'<h6 class="text-center">'.$latest_filename.'</h6>';
    echo '<table class=" table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" style="width:100%">';
    echo'<tbody>';

    $f = fopen("$path/$latest_filename", "r");

    while (($row = fgetcsv($f, 1000, ";")) !== false) {
        //Create table using the filename as tablename, if table already exist insert data.
        $csv->createCsvTable($row);

            echo '<tr>';
            foreach ($row as $cell) {
                echo '<td>' .htmlspecialchars($cell, ENT_COMPAT). '</td>';

            }
            echo '</tr>';
    }
    fclose($f);
    echo'</tbody>';
    echo '</table>';


//csv table end
    ?><table id="example" class="table-hover  table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Datum</th>
            <th scope="col">Property</th>
            <th scope="col">Criterion</th>
            <th scope="col">Type</th>
            <th scope="col">Nominal</th>
            <th scope="col">Actual</th>            
            <th scope="col">Tol-</th>                
            <th scope="col">Tol+</th>
            <th scope="col">Dev</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($csv->getCsv() as $csv) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $csv->Name; ?></td>
                <td><?= $csv->Datum; ?></td>
                <td><?= $csv->Property; ?></td>
                <td><?= $csv->Criterion; ?></td>
                <td><?= $csv->Type; ?></td>
                <td><?= $csv->Nominal; ?></td>
                <td><?= $csv->Actual; ?></td>
                <td><?= $csv->Tolminus; ?></td>
                <td><?= $csv->Tolplus; ?></td>
                <td><?= $csv->Dev; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php }?>
    </tbody>

</table>
 <?php }
```

And here is my CSV class in which I have no clue how to write the `createCsvTable` What I want it to do is insert the csv files data into the table I've created.

```
<?php

class Csv extends \PDO {

private $db = null;



/**
 * Settings constructor.
 */
public function __construct($db)
{
    $this->db = $db;
}

/**
 * Menu & Admin Menu
 * @return mixed
 */

public function getCsv()
{
    return $this->db->toList("SELECT * FROM Test");
}

   public function createCsvTable()
    {
        return $this->db->toList("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test(
            id int (11),
            Name VARCHAR(30), 
            Datum VARCHAR(30), 
            Property VARCHAR(30), 
            Criterion VARCHAR(30), 
            Type VARCHAR(30), 
            Nominal DECIMAL(10,2), 
            Actual DECIMAL(10,2), 
            Tolminus DECIMAL(10,2), 
            Tolplus DECIMAL(10,2), 
            Dev DECIMAL(10,2)
          );
          /* INSERT QUERY */
          INSERT INTO Testeses(
            id, Name, Datum, Property, Criterion, Type, 
            Nominal, Actual, Tolminus, Tolplus, Dev
          ) 
          VALUES 
            (
              ?,?,?,?,?,?, 
              ?,?,?,?,?
            );");
    }
}
```

I know that if I replaced the ? with some actual data it would be inserted, but I need it to be from the csv file. that is the main problem

**So just to be clear, my question is "How can I insert data from my csv file into my database?"**

also if you know how to name the table after the filename I would be ever grateful.

Comment: something like this tutorial ? https://www.cloudways.com/blog/import-export-csv-using-php-and-mysql/

Comment: well kinda but i dont need to store the name of the file in my database i need the file as a table in my database

Comment: What have you tried? What is the exact problem? Writing a loop that reads the data from the file and runs the proper queries is not that hard

Comment: As @NicoHaase said. Loop through csv file read rows one by one and insert it into your database.

Comment: What i have tried to do is, at first i wanted to just be able to see the file on my site, but since i need to work with it now i need to store it in my database, so i can use the data from it. but i do not know how to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing and head scratching i've found a somewhat good solution. what this does is

1. it looks into the directory.
2. finds the newest file.
3. creates a copy of the newest file and sends it to a other directory.
4. creates a table named after the newest file using the CSV.php file.
5. it then opens the copied file takes the data.
6. create an array from the data (from what i understand).
7. counts the data.
8. joins the array elements with a string.
9. splits that string into "cells/single values"
10. And then inserts the data into the table.

> A note for those who might want to use it. be aware of this ";" You
>   might have to change that to "," depending on how your file is
>   seperated. my file is seperated using the ";" and i am using
>   `utf8_encode` so that i can use special characters like ÆØÅ
>   The changes you have to make is located in this while.

```
while ($getdata = fgetcsv($openfile, 1000, ";")) {
$getdata = array_map("utf8_encode", $getdata);
$total = count($getdata);
//    echo "<b>Row no:-</b>$row\n";   
//    echo "<b>Total fields in this row:-</b>$total\n";
$row++;
for ($c=0; $c < $total; $c++) {
    $csvdata = implode(";", $getdata);
    $fncsvdata = explode(";", $csvdata);
}
```

I have also created a table to show how i get the output on my site.

**Here is the answer**

This is the file that the user sees. in my case its called `csvtable.php`

```
<?php
    // File selector
    $path = "./assets/csv"; 
    $sourcepath = "assets/csv"; 
    $copy = "assets/proceskontrol-csv";
    $latest_ctime = 0;
    $latest_filename = '';    

    $d = dir($path);
    while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
    $filepath = "{$path}/{$entry}";
    // could do also other checks than just checking whether the entry is a file
        if (is_file($filepath) && filectime($filepath) > $latest_ctime){
            $latest_ctime = filectime($filepath);
            $latest_filename = $entry;
        }
    }
    if (1+1 == 2){
        copy("$sourcepath/$latest_filename","$copy/$latest_filename");
        $csv->createCsvTable($latest_filename);
        $row = 1;
        if (($openfile = fopen("$copy/$latest_filename", "r")) !== FALSE) {
            while ($getdata = fgetcsv($openfile, 1000, ";")) {
                $getdata = array_map("utf8_encode", $getdata);
                $total = count($getdata);
                //    echo "<b>Row no:-</b>$row\n";   
                //    echo "<b>Total fields in this row:-</b>$total\n";
                $row++;
                for ($c=0; $c < $total; $c++) {
                    $csvdata = implode(";", $getdata);
                    $fncsvdata = explode(";", $csvdata);
                }
                $csv->insertCsvTable($latest_filename ,$fncsvdata);
            }
        }
    }
    echo'<h1 class="text-center">CSV Table</h1>';
    echo'<h6 class="text-center">'.$latest_filename.'</h6>';
    echo '<table class=" table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">';
    echo'<tbody>';
?>

    <table class="table-hover table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>   
            <th scope="col">id</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Datum</th>
            <th scope="col">Property</th>
            <th scope="col">Criterion</th>
            <th scope="col">Type</th>
            <th scope="col">Nominal</th>
            <th scope="col">Actual</th>            
            <th scope="col">Tol-</th>                
            <th scope="col">Tol+</th>
            <th scope="col">Dev</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($csv->getCsv($latest_filename) as $csv) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $csv->id; ?></td>
                <td><?= $csv->Name; ?></td>
                <td><?= $csv->Datum; ?></td>
                <td><?= $csv->Property; ?></td>
                <td><?= $csv->Criterion; ?></td>
                <td><?= $csv->Type; ?></td>
                <td><?= $csv->Nominal; ?></td>
                <td><?= $csv->Actual; ?></td>
                <td><?= $csv->Tolminus; ?></td>
                <td><?= $csv->Tolplus; ?></td>
                <td><?= $csv->Dev; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php }?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my database class file `DB.php`. used alot in the `CSV.php`

```
<?php
class DB extends \PDO
{
    /**
     * @var
     */
    private $host;
    /**
     * @var
     */
    private $user;
    /**
     * @var
     */
    private $pass;
    /**
     * @var PDO
     */
    private $conn;
    /**
     * @var
     */
    private $query;
    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    private $debug = false;


    /**
     * @param bool $bool
     */
    public function debug($bool = true)
    {
        $this->debug = $bool;
    }

    /**
     * @param $sql
     */
    private function setQuery($sql)
    {
        $this->query = $this->prepare($sql);
    }

    /**
     * DB constructor.
     * @param $dbhost
     * @param $dbuser
     * @param $dbpass
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function __construct($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $options = [])
    {
        try {
            $this->conn = parent::__construct($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $options);
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            print "Fejl!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
            die();
        }

    }


    /**
     * @param string $sql
     * @param bool $params
     * @param int|mixed|null $returnType
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function query($sql, $params = false, $returnType = \PDO::FETCH_OBJ)
    {
        $this->setQuery($sql);
        $this->execute($params);
        $this->count = $this->query->rowCount();

        return $this->query->fetchAll($returnType);
    }

    /**
     * @param $params
     */
    private function execute($params)
    {
        if($params){
            $this->query->execute($params);
        } else {
            $this->query->execute();
        }
        if($this->debug){
            echo '<pre id="debug_params">',$this->query->debugDumpParams(),'</pre>';
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $sql
     * @param bool $params
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function single($sql, $params = false){
        $data = $this->query($sql, $params);
        if(sizeof($data) === 1){
            return $data[0];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $sql
     * @param bool $params
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function first($sql, $params = false){
        return $this->query($sql, $params)[0];
    }

    /**
     * @param $sql
     * @param bool $params
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function last($sql, $params = false){
        return $this->query($sql, $params)[$this->count - 1];
    }

    /**
     * @param $sql
     * @param bool $params
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function toList($sql, $params = false){
        return $this->query($sql, $params);
    }

    /**
     * @param $sql
     * @param bool $params
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function lastId($sql, $params = false){
        $this->query($sql, $params);
        return $this->lastInsertId();
    }
}
```

And this is the `CSV.php` this is where i create my tables and insert the data. (the sql calls)

```
<?php
class Csv extends \PDO {

    private $db = null;



    /**
     * Settings constructor.
     */
    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    /**
     * Menu & Admin Menu
     * @return mixed
     */

    public function getCsv($latest_filename)
    {
        return $this->db->toList("SELECT * FROM `$latest_filename`");
    }

    public function createCsvTable($latest_filename)

    {
        return $this->db->toList("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$latest_filename`(
            id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            Name VARCHAR(50), 
            Datum VARCHAR(50), 
            Property VARCHAR(50), 
            Criterion VARCHAR(50), 
            Type VARCHAR(50), 
            Nominal DECIMAL(10,2), 
            Actual DECIMAL(10,2), 
            Tolminus DECIMAL(10,2), 
            Tolplus DECIMAL(10,2), 
            Dev DECIMAL(10,2))
        ");
    }
    public function insertCsvTable($latest_filename ,$fncsvdata)
    {
        return $this->db->toList("INSERT INTO `$latest_filename` (`Name`,  `Datum`, `Property`, `Criterion`, `Type`, `Nominal`, `Actual`,`Tolminus`,`Tolplus`,`Dev`)
        VALUES (:Name, :Datum, :Property, :Criterion, :Type, :Nominal, :Actual, :Tolminus, :Tolplus, :Dev)",
            [
            ':Name' => $fncsvdata[0],
            ':Datum'=> $fncsvdata[1],
            ':Property'=> $fncsvdata[2],
            ':Criterion'=> $fncsvdata[3],
            ':Type'=> $fncsvdata[4],
            ':Nominal'=> $fncsvdata[5],
            ':Actual'=> $fncsvdata[6],
            ':Tolminus'=> $fncsvdata[7],
            ':Tolplus'=> $fncsvdata[8],
            ':Dev'=> $fncsvdata[9]
            ]);
    }
}
```

I really hope someone can use this.

Answer (score 0):

CSV is a 'comma seperated value' format and in your database you have "indexes". So to save a csv file you need to load it, loop through every line and then insert it with a query. So your code could look like this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO Testeses(id, Name, Datum, ...)
                       VALUES (
                               :id, :name, :date, ...
                       );');
foreach($csvLines as $line) {
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', $line[0]);
    $stmt->bindValue(':name', $line[1]);
    $stmt->bindValue(':date', $line[2]);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

You need to know at which position a specific value is located.

Comment: To name the table same as the csv file you can replace the name of the table in the replace QUERY with the '$latest_filename' variable that you use to load the file

Comment: Do you have a problem with inserting the data or with the table name? Posting the whole function as new answer...

Comment: I have a problem with data in my table not being inserted, the table is created but no data.

Comment: would be very grateful if you did that :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting a solution below. Maybe read this to learn about PDO and PreparedStatements so you understand how to bind them to columns.
You need to change the methods execute and prepare to you pdo object, because I don't know how you managed it there to execute the statements.

```
public function createCsvTable($file_name, $lines)
    {
        $tableCreation = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " . $file_name . "(
            id int (11),
            Name VARCHAR(30), 
            Datum VARCHAR(30), 
            Property VARCHAR(30), 
            Criterion VARCHAR(30), 
            Type VARCHAR(30), 
            Nominal DECIMAL(10,2), 
            Actual DECIMAL(10,2), 
            Tolminus DECIMAL(10,2), 
            Tolplus DECIMAL(10,2), 
            Dev DECIMAL(10,2)
          );";
          $stmt = execute($tableCreation);

          $insertion = "INSERT INTO " . $file_name . "(
            id, Name, Datum, Property, Criterion, Type, 
            Nominal, Actual, Tolminus, Tolplus, Dev
          ) 
          VALUES 
            (
              ?,?,?,?,?,?, 
              ?,?,?,?,?
            );");
         $stmt = prepare($insertion);
         foreach ($lines as $line) {
             $stmt->bindParam(1, $line[0]);
             // do for every parameter
             $stmt->execute();
         }

    }
```

Comment: And then change the values to :id :name and so on?

Comment: That would be my preferred way, yes.

Comment: ohh okay, i will look into it. i have added my DB class to the question since you said you didnt understand how i executed my data.